# Push уведомления и автоотправка СМС с пользовательского устройста с его разрешения Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Может кто-нибудь подсказать по этим двум задачам? (Как програмить, что для этого нужно). Я так понял это достаточно сложно.
Возможно ли настроить авто отправку СМС с устройства пользователя с его разрешения в определенную дату?

Answer (score 1):

На прямую с устройства автоматически СМС отправлять нельзя, читайте документацию Apple. Вы можете настроить локальные оповещения в определенное время, и если уж очень надо, поднимайте сторонний сервис с отправкой СМС.

Comment: В моем приложении автоотправка СМС просто необходима. Тяжело ли реализовать его начинающему программеру?

Comment: С телефона автоматически это не возможно. Вы можете только префил делать и пользователь должен сам нажать на "Отправить". Второй вариант ищите сторонние сервесы отправки СМС и тогда ваше приложение отправляет запрос в данный сервис и он отправит СМС